# How can I update object from database without inserting new?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, thymeleaf

i want to update object from my database without inserting new to the DB.

here are 2 methods:

```
@RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
    public ModelAndView showEditProductPage(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id, Model model) {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("edit_customer");

        Customer customer = customerService.getCustomer(id);
        //Customer customer = customerRepository.getOne(id);
        //customer.setCustomerId(customerRepository.getOne(id).getCustomerId());
        System.out.println(customer.getCustomerId());
        System.out.println(customer.toString());
        model.addAttribute("customer", customer);
        modelAndView.addObject("customer", customer);
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

output is: id=1 Customer{id=1, firstName='Krzysztof', address='ulica 1', phoneNumber='123456789'}

```
@RequestMapping("/update/{id}")
    public String updateCustomer(@PathVariable(name = "id") Integer id,
                                 @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer){
        //System.out.println(id);
        //customer.setCustomerId(id);
        System.out.println("____________________");
        System.out.println("customer id " + customer.getCustomerId());
        System.out.println("____________________");
        customer.setCustomerId(id);
        System.out.println("customer id " + customer.getCustomerId());
        System.out.println("owner " + customer.getOwner());
        System.out.println("address " + customer.getAddress());
        System.out.println("phone number " + customer.getAddress());
        System.out.println("to string: " + customer.toString());
        System.out.println("id " + id);
        customerService.save(customer);

        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

output after second method is: id=1 Customer{id=null, firstName='Krzysztof', address='ulica 1zzz', phoneNumber='123456789'}

customer repository extends JPA repository,
save method:

```
public void save(Customer customer) {
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }
```

thymeleaf template:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Edit Customer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/table.css}" />
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Edit Customer</h1>
    <a href="/">Go Back</a>
    <br />
    <form action="#" th:action="@{'/update/' + ${id}}" th:object="${customer}"
          method="post">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
                <td>Customer ID:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{customerId}" readonly="readonly" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>First Name:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" th:field="*{owner}" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{address}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Phone Number:</td>
                <td><input type="text" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button type="submit">Save</button> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

customer entity class:

```
package com.praca.manager.entity;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer customerId;

    @Column(name = "owner")
    private String owner;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
    List<Details> details;

    public Customer(){
    }

    public Customer(Integer customerId,
                    String owner,
                    String address,
                    String phoneNumber){
                        this.customerId = customerId;
                        this.owner = owner;
                        this.address = address;
                        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public Integer getCustomerId() {

        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(Integer id){

        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getOwner() {

        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String firstName) {

        this.owner = firstName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {

        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){

        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {

        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {

        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + customerId +
                ", firstName='" + owner + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", phoneNumber='" + phoneNumber + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

here ID field is also '1'
sql script:

```
create table customer(
customer_id int auto_increment primary key not null,
owner varchar(200) not null,
address varchar(200) not null,
phone_number int not null
);
```

despite i try to set id to 1 or any other number, it is still null.
Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

Comment: Post your `Customer` entity class

Comment: I suspect an issue with your `id` generation strategy and I guess your id is not `autoincrement`?

Comment: posted at the bottom of the original post

Comment: it is autoincrement, i will edit post with sql in a moment

Comment: Set this : `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`

Comment: it resulted with exception:       java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'customercdkomp.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist

Comment: What is your database behind?

Comment: MySql, i edited the post with sql script

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227737/discussion-between-harry-coder-and-maszpet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the setter of your Customer class:

```
public void setCustomerId(Integer id){

    this.customerId = customerId;
}
```

You assigned the field to itself, that's why it's always null. Should be "this.customerId = id" :).